# UILabel in custom UICollectionViewCell always null, can't update text

Tags: ios, ios6, storyboard, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I created a collection view very simple to an Apple collection view sample project. I have a collection view in a view controller in storyboard, and set a label inside the collection view cell in the top right part of the collection view. I've hooked that up to the IBOutlet in my custom cell. Here's the relevant code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.workoutView registerClass:[Cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    ...
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (collectionView == self.collView) {
        Cell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];    
        cell.segmentTitle.text = @"some text";
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

I put a breakpoint after the `segmentTitle.text` part and segmentTitle is always null. Accordingly what I see in the simulator is empty white boxes. What did I miss?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

UICollectionViewCell inside StoryBoard don't need to registerClass, just choose reuseidentifier in StoryBoard. Delete this line:

```
   // [self.workoutView registerClass:[Cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

And make sure you connect right way:

-Select class type of UICollectionViewCell in storyBoard to Cell

-Drag UILabel into Cell and hook up to Cell.h

-Type the reuse identifier

Comment: Removing the register line and using the reuse identifier from storyboard fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: This works. Sometimes there's just too much magic in storyboard.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by -Type the reuse identifier ? I deleted the first line but I can't see anything (did the other steps)

Comment: @Signo Type it in your storyboard

Comment: yeah found it :) now I just need to understand why the width and height aren't updated and i'm fine :P thanks!

Comment: Thanks it solved my bug... I spent 1.5 valuable hours behind it.

Comment: was trying to work out why this wasn't working for hours. removing the registerClass worked a treat

Answer (score 2):

```
MainFeedCollectionView.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
```

I removed this line from my code now its now working fine...